# What do you call a roster with people's faces?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering what the correct term for a roster of names (e.g., for a class, team or department) that contains each individual's picture.

My high school called such a roster a "*face book*" because theirs consisted of an actual book for the whole school.

- Because of facebook.com, this phrase is misleading (i.e., it now carries a much different connotation).
- Further, the popularity of Facebook.com makes trying to confirm the usage of the word "facebook" as I've suggested difficult to do using online searches.

So I thought perhaps "*face sheet*" would work, but this is apparently another name for a cover letter.

There's got to be something better than "*roster with pictures*."

- Is "*Photo roster*" used very often?

I'm looking for the phrase that is used most ubiquitously.

Comment: Yearbook is what we called those when I was in high school in the 90s.  Do they still make yearbooks these days?

Comment: Use "facebook", which designates exactly what you are talking about; the online  this is slang (which arose, I think, in the 70s). The online behemoth took its name from this. You may confirm this use online by looking for books published before 2004, when facebook.com was founded.

Comment: @thomj1332 "Yearbooks" or "annuals" are published at the end of the year as a memento/record of people and events; a "facebook" is typically a directory with photographs for use during the year.

Comment: Thanks StoneyB for confirming that this was more common than just at my high school. Your comment was essentially my understanding of the situation...But again, with Facebook.com being so popular, using the term "facebook" now carries a much different connotation.

Comment: To the other comments: I'm not referring to a yearbook, but rather a roster used for more regular access to people's names/appearances or used for getting to learn people's names. I suppose a yearbook would technically fall under the same umbrella usage, but hopefully I've clarified what I'm interested in.

Comment: Perhaps 'a list of profiles'?

Comment: Probably not what you want, but what came to mind for me was **rogues gallery**.

Comment: Just because Facebook.Com has developed itself into something much more, surely doesn't mean it does or anyone else should deny its origins… does it?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin no not at all. The issue is simply having people know/understand what you're talking about. Mentioning a facebook will almost certainly require a follow-up statement indicating you don't mean the website. I'd guess a minority of folks today would have any idea there is anything *but* the website even after the explanation!

Comment: That's terribly sad and if the context won't clue your readers in, can you not get the message across with something very like *a book of faces*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a roster used for more regular access to people's names/appearances
>   or used for getting to learn people's names.

I believe it's called a ***photo directory***. It gets ~423,000,000 results on Google - here's are just two examples:

> Each year, the pictures taken of you, your classmates, faculty and
>   staff during orientation find their way into the Law School
>   Photographic Directory, which becomes available soon after fall
>   classes start.  The Photo Directory is available online and will give
>   you a good start on associating names with the faces of your student
>   colleagues and recognizing the faculty and staff.

https://www.law.umich.edu/currentstudents/studentservices/handbook/genlinfo/Pages/Law%20School%20Photo%20Directory.aspx

[image]

https://www.chicagobooth.edu/faculty/faculty-photo-directory

Comment: I think other than stubbornly just using the phrase "facebook", this is certainly a very understandable and straightforward approach. Thanks for the suggestion! +1